# Array that Holds JButton Objects

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

Ok, so I'm attempting to do an exercise from a book I'm using to learn Java. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
public class Calculator {
    //Declaration of all calculator's components.
    JPanel windowContent;
    JTextField displayField;
    JButton button0;
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;
    JButton button3;
    JButton button4;
    JButton button5;
    JButton button6;
    JButton button7;
    JButton button8;
    JButton button9;
    JButton buttonPoint;
    JButton buttonAdd;
    JButton buttonEqual;
    JPanel pl;

    //Constructor creates the components in memory and adds the to the frame using combination of Borderlayout.
    Calculator() {
        windowContent= new JPanel();

    // Set the layout manager for this panel
        BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
        windowContent.setLayout(bl);

    //Create the display field and place it in the North area of the window
        displayField = new JTextField(30);
        windowContent.add("North",displayField);

    //Create button field and place it in the North area of the window
        button0=new JButton("0");
        button1=new JButton("1");
        button2=new JButton("2");
        button3=new JButton("3");
        button4=new JButton("4");
        button5=new JButton("5");
        button6=new JButton("6");
        button7=new JButton("7");
        button8=new JButton("8");
        button9=new JButton("9");
        buttonAdd=new JButton("+");
        buttonPoint = new JButton(".");
        buttonEqual=new JButton("=");

    //Create the panel with the GridLayout that will contain 12 buttons - 10 numeric ones, and button with the points
    //and the equal sign.
        pl = new JPanel ();
        GridLayout gl =new GridLayout(4,3);
        pl.setLayout(gl);
    //Add window controls to the panel pl.
        pl.add(button1);
        pl.add(button2);
        pl.add(button3);
        pl.add(button4);
        pl.add(button5);
        pl.add(button6);
        pl.add(button7);
        pl.add(button8);
        pl.add(button9);
        pl.add(buttonAdd);
        pl.add(buttonPoint);
        pl.add(buttonEqual);

    //Add the panel pl to the center area of the window
        windowContent.add("Center",pl);
    //Create the frame and set its content pane
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setContentPane(windowContent);
    //set the size of the window to be big enough to accomodate all controls.
        frame.pack();
    //Finnaly, display the window
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    }
}
```

Here is the exercise in exact wording:

> Modify the class Calculator.java to keep all numeric buttons in the 10-element array declared as follows:
>
> `Buttons[] numButtons= new Buttons[10];`
>
> Replace 10 lines that start from
>
> `button0=new JButton("0");`
>
> with a loop that creates the buttons and store them in this array.

Ok, so I tried declaring the array with the `Buttons[] numbuttons line`, but that just gave me the error:

> Multiple markers at this line
>   -Buttons can not be resolved to a type
>   -Buttons can not be resolved to a type

I instead tried this:

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[10]
```

And then added each button to the array like this:

```
buttons[0] = "button0";
```

Doing this didn't give me an error when I declared the array, but when I wrote the `buttons[0]` line, I got this error:

> Syntax error on token "buttons",delete this token

So, I need help figuring out how to do this. Also, the book can be found here: http://myflex.org/books/java4kids/JavaKid811.pdf and the practice is on page 73.
I apologize if I'm listing to much information. It's just because I'm very new to Java and I'm not sure what is necessary. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `buttons` is an array of `JButton`s, not `String`s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are doing is trying to set the array space to a string when you need a JButton.

You should be doing this

```
buttons[0] = new JButton("0");
```

instead of

```
buttons[0] = "button0";
```

EDIT:

I just did this

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JButton[] buttons = new JButton[10];

        buttons[0] = new JButton("0");

        System.out.println(buttons[0].getText());
    }

}
```

and got

```
0
```

for an output so your error isn't in that line.

EDIT: Code

Calculator.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class Calculator {
    //Declaration of all calculator's components.
    JPanel windowContent;
    JTextField displayField;
    JButton buttons[];
    JButton buttonPoint;
    JButton buttonAdd;
    JButton buttonEqual;
    JPanel pl;

    //Constructor creates the components in memory and adds the to the frame using combination of Borderlayout.
    Calculator() {
        windowContent= new JPanel();
        buttons = new JButton[10];

    // Set the layout manager for this panel
        BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
        windowContent.setLayout(bl);

    //Create the display field and place it in the North area of the window
        displayField = new JTextField(30);
        windowContent.add("North",displayField);

    //Create button field and place it in the North area of the window
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        buttonAdd=new JButton("+");
        buttonPoint = new JButton(".");
        buttonEqual=new JButton("=");

    //Create the panel with the GridLayout that will contain 12 buttons - 10 numeric ones, and button with the points
    //and the equal sign.
        pl = new JPanel ();
        GridLayout gl =new GridLayout(4,3);
        pl.setLayout(gl);
    //Add window controls to the panel pl.

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            pl.add(buttons[i]);
        }
        pl.add(buttonAdd);
        pl.add(buttonPoint);
        pl.add(buttonEqual);

    //Add the panel pl to the center area of the window
        windowContent.add("Center",pl);
    //Create the frame and set its content pane
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
        frame.setContentPane(windowContent);
    //set the size of the window to be big enough to accomodate all controls.
        frame.pack();
    //Finnaly, display the window
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what do you think the problem is?

Comment: I just took your code from above changed all the buttons (0-9) into an array called buttons updated all the references and it compiles fine.

Comment: everywhere it said button1 (or button2 etc) I changed it to buttons[1] (or buttons[2] etc).

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty sure I just did all that, and I'm getting the same error when I make my array, could you post the whole program that you made for me? Then I could see what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Sure I'll edit my answer (I also did somethings that made it more useful Now the number keys work)

Comment: It says my action listener can not be resolved as a type when I copied that code into eclipse.

Comment: Oh, I see, I need the MyActionListener, could you post the code without the listener stuff? I appreciate it, but I'm gonna do all that from the book so I really get an understanding of it.

Comment: Ok I'll got rid of the actionListener.

Answer (score 2):

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[10]
```

The line above is correct, but I see two points of confusion:

1. This line:

   ```
   buttons[0] = "button0";
   ```

   should instead be as follows:

   ```
   buttons[0] = new JButton("button0");
   ```

   The reason is that in your code, you're trying to assign a `String` to `buttons[0]`, instead of the expected `JButton`.
2. > Ok, so I tried declaring the array with the Buttons[] numbuttons line,
   >   but that just gave me the error: Multiple markers at this line
   >   -Buttons can not be resolved to a type -Buttons can not be resolved to a type

   `Buttons` is not a standard Java class. Do a case-sensitive search
   for `Buttons` and replace all matches with `JButton`.

If you still have problems, please copy and paste the *exact code* for each variation that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, you need the loop to instantiate and store the JButtons.

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    numButton[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

You need to convert the loop control variable into a String argument for the JButton constructor.

Comment: Well, right now, the problem isn't creating a loop, it's creating one normal part of the array. Any help on that?\

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "one normal part of the array"?

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
buttons[0] = button0;
```

and not

```
buttons[0] = "button0";
```

Comment: That returns the same error as before, Syntax error on token "buttons", delete this token

Comment: Can you please paste the code here for us to see how exactly you are implementing the array.

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, you are trying to put a string in an array made for JButtons.  Java doesn't like you mixing datatypes in this way, and throws an error.