# Looping to make JButtons that hold their name values

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

EDIT: The answer to the button generating part of this question can be found here: 
[Array that Holds JButton Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814566/array-that-holds-jbutton-objects)

I used a for loop to generate some JButtons each labeled with their index. Within the loop, I attach an ActionListener to each button. The listener retrieves the label of the button and prints it. Currently, the only button which returns a value is the last one created, which makes sense. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this sort of mass-generation and then individual retrieval in an advantageous way.

IN SHORT:

Make a bunch of labeled JButtons in a loop. 
Print the label when a button is clicked.

Here is a short, executable example of what my current process looks like:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class calc {
private JFrame mainFrame;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private JButton button;

public calc(){
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Calculator");
    mainPanel = new JPanel();

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        int value = i;
        String number = Integer.toString(value);
        button = new JButton(number);
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        mainFrame.add(button);
    }
    mainFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    mainFrame.setSize(250, 300);
    mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          if (e.getSource() == button) {
           System.out.println(((JButton) e.getSource()).getText());
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `Currently, the only button which returns a value is the last one created` What do you mean by this? Currently you only have one button.

Comment: Buttons are created for 0-9, when clicked button nine returns "9" in the console. None of the others return any kind of value, null or otherwise.

Comment: See my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of buttons, for example:

```
JButton[] btns = new JButtons[10];
for(int x=0; x<btns.length; x++)
    btns[x] = new JButton(x + "");
```

Create your ActionListener:

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println( ((JButton)e.getSource()).getText() );
    }
}
```

Add each button to the ActionListener:

```
ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
for(int x=0=; x<btns.length; x++)
    btns[x].addActionListener(handler);
```

When you click any of the buttons, it will trigger the ActionListener and based on the button that was clicked, print the text from the JButton to the console.

Comment: Makes sense, but how would one add these to a frame? They can no longer be added simply with ".add".

Comment: You should also note that you could add the listener to the buttons in the same loop that creates the buttons. @CodeBoy You should still be able to add them with `.add`, you just have to do it one button at a time (can also be done in the loop that creates the buttons: create, add listener, add to frame. all in 1 loop)

Comment: @CodeBoy. Not only that they can still be added. You can do it with much lesser lines of codes by using a loop.

Comment: I put the .add section into my loop, but my compiler still flags it with this warning–" Change the type of 'button' to 'Component' ". 'button' is the variable name for the buttons.

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {mainPanel.add(button[i]);
         }

Comment: ^figured it out; for anyone looking at this in the future.