# One action on many jButtons

Tags: java, swing, random, jbutton

I would like to use one function on 50 jButtons, it suppose to be numeric majong game, I would like to put random numbers into all 50 jbuttons with one method.

```
int r = randInt(1,50);
        jButton1.setText(Integer.toString(r));
```

This is one, but i have no idea, how to make it same for 50 others. All i can figure is copy paste it 50 times and change number of the button.

Comment: Use an array to store the `JButton`s.

Comment: Help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814566/array-that-holds-jbutton-objects

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly store those buttons in an array, then you could use a simple for loop to execute the method on each element.

For example:

```
//JButtonArray is an array of JButton objects
for(int i=0; i < JButtonArray.length; i++) {
    r = randInt(1,50);
    JButtonArray[i].setText(Integer.toString(r));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use [Darryl Burke's SwingUtils class](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) and find all JButtons in a Panel- Container, and then, do whatever you want with them. This has higher complexity (but it does not require to "save" all jbuttons somewhere) for sure and here is not required necessarily, but you might find it useful one day in the future. For example, to iterate the buttons of a `JOptionPane`.

A SSCCE using this method:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AllJButtons extends JFrame {
    public AllJButtons() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 5));
        //Let's say somehow, we add the buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            JButton btn = new JButton("Button ID=" + i);
            getContentPane().add(btn);
        }
        //Now iterate all buttons and add them red border.
        for (JButton button : getDescendantsOfType(JButton.class, getContentPane(), false)) {
            button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        }
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    /**
    * Convenience method for searching below <code>container</code> in the
    * component hierarchy and return nested components that are instances of
    * class <code>clazz</code> it finds. Returns an empty list if no such
    * components exist in the container.
    * <P>
    * Invoking this method with a class parameter of JComponent.class
    * will return all nested components.
    * 
    * @param clazz the class of components whose instances are to be found.
    * @param container the container at which to begin the search
    * @param nested true to list components nested within another listed
    * component, false otherwise
    * @return the List of components
    */
    public static <T extends JComponent> List<T> getDescendantsOfType(Class<T> clazz, Container container, boolean nested) {
        List<T> tList = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (Component component : container.getComponents()) {
            if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(component.getClass())) {
                tList.add(clazz.cast(component));
            }
            if (nested || !clazz.isAssignableFrom(component.getClass())) {
                tList.addAll(AllJButtons.<T>getDescendantsOfType(clazz, (Container) component, nested));
            }
        }
        return tList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new AllJButtons().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```